# How to identify transactions that were purchased during a sale or at a discount

Tags: transactions, product, point-of-sale, discount, feasibility

I'm trying to develop a proof of concept and determine if this is technically feasible - If I purchase an item at a discount from its normal listed price (i.e. the normal full price is $20 but I bought it on sale for $15) from a retailer online or in-store and I go into my credit card transaction history it will solely show that there was a purchase of $15. Is there a method to determine if this $15 purchase occurred at a discount from the normal full price?

If this is possible I want to trigger a deposit according to a certain predefined threshold.

i.e. if an item was purchased at a discount from its normal listed price and the final sale price after discount is:

- $1 - 25: trigger a deposit of 5% the sale price into account
- $26 - 50: trigger a deposit of 4% the sale price into account
- $51 - 75: trigger a deposit of 3% the sale price into account
- $76 - 100: trigger a deposit of 2% the sale price into account
- $101+: trigger a deposit of 1% the sale price into account

Code (any language) would be helpful but ultimately looking for an answer to technical feasibility, what would be some requirements, and the effort involved.

Thank you in advance!